# Java: How do you style Swing components?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

I'm writing my first Java project.

I was wondering if it's possible to style the Swing components (set a background color, remove the borders from the buttons, etc.)

Answer (score 6):

If it's as simple as just changing the font, the background, the borders etc. Swing can do all these by default. I.e. for a JButton:

```
JButton aButton ...
aButton.setBackground(new Color(...));  
aButton.setForeground(new Color(...));  
aButton.setFont(new Font(...));  
aButton.setBorder(null);
```

Have a look at most of these methods at the [JComponent](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html). Or, for more component-specific methods, at the component's javadoc.

I would recommend you to read some basics in [The Java Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) or the [JComponent API](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html) or even a book such as [Filthy Rich Clients](http://filthyrichclients.org/) or [Java HowTo Program](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132222205).

A custom Look and Feel would be a little too much. I suggest to first see if the above solutions don't fit your needs and then go for that.

Comment: This is not really true: setFont, setColor... are not static methods, they don't allow you to set defaults for each kind of component.

Comment: Um.. Maybe I shouldn't used JComponent. I didn't mean that they are static rather that most classes subclassing JComponent (JButton, JLabel etc.) inherit these methods.. Let me clarify that better..

Answer (score 3):

It's certainly possible to do significant customisations because that is what the different look and feel options do.

You could look at the [pluggable look and feel architecture](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/sce/index.html), though this may be way overkill for what you want.

Alternatively you could perhaps subclass the existing components and use/override their existing methods, if it is only minor tweaks you need.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few open soruce projects that allow you to style Swing components with CSS-like format.

You should take a look at the [Java CSS](http://javacss.dev.java.net/) project. It was introduced in [this blog post](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/enicholas/archive/2008/07/introducing_jav.html).

Answer (score 1):

For an application wide change, creating (or extending) your own [pluggable look and feel](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/sce/index.html) is probably the correct solution. For special effects, you should also take a look at the [painters framework](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/joshy/archive/2006/09/introducing_pai.html). Note that they are part of swingx, not core Swing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to style your components heavily, getting a 3rd party Look-And-Feel and using that may be your best choice. My personal favorite is [Substance](http://insubstantial.github.io/insubstantial/substance/) which even has an API for creating completely custom LAFs on top of Substance.